# overloading the + operator in a class with a pointer member variable

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I've a very simple class. It has a pointer member variable. I want to overload the + operator. But, it doesn't work! Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <typename T> 
struct Node{
    Node *next;
    T data;
};

template <typename T> 
class stack{
protected:
    Node <T> *head;

public:
    stack();
    ~stack();
    bool push(T);
    stack <T> operator+ (stack <T>);

};

template <typename T> 
stack<T>::stack(){
    head = NULL;
}

template <typename T>  
stack <T>::~stack(){
    Node <T> *temp;

    while(head){
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

template <typename T> 
bool stack <T>::push(T data){
    Node <T> *newElem = new Node <T>;
    if (!newElem) return false;

    newElem->next = head;
    newElem->data = data;
    head = newElem;
    return true;
}

template <typename T> 
stack <T> stack<T>::operator+ (stack <T> stack1){
    stack <T> result;
    Node <T> *temp = head;

    while (temp) {
        result.push(temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp = stack1.head;
    while (temp) {
        result.push(temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(){
    stack <int> myStack1, myStack2, myStack3;

    myStack1.push (1);
    myStack1.push (2);

    myStack2.push (3);
    myStack2.push (4);

    myStack3 = myStack1 + myStack2; //  here at runtime myStack3 is not the result of myStack1 + myStack2. 
    return 0;
}
```

Could you please help me with this? 
Please note that this is just for practice.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What are you trying to show with the last line `myStack3 = myStack1 = myStack2;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating a **copy** of the right-hand side of the operator. The signature should be:

```
template <typename T> 
stack <T> stack<T>::operator+ (const stack <T>& stack1) { ... }
```

so that you are only referencing `stack1`, not copying it.

This will fix the immediate problem you have, but long term, you also want to implement a correct copy-constructor as all copies of a `stack` will currently **corrupt the memory** as they link the same elements and the destrutor will delete them, the other `stack` then still **references the deleted elements**.

This is why you see "result" having the expected value, the copy called `stack1` has not yet been deleted. But when the `operator+` returns, it deletes `stack1` and therefore all elements of `stack1` are deleted. Not all pointers that were copied to the result that refer to elements from `stack1` are invalid. This is why `stack3` appears broken after the call.

See also the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722), read the "Managing resources" section in the answer.

---

Update: This is not enough as you also assign the result of `operator+`, again the rule of three applies as you don't have a correct assignment operator as well. You probably want to add these to your class:

```
template <typename T> 
stack<T>::stack(const stack<T>& src)
{
    // this will reverse the src, I'll leave it to you to fix the order!
    head = NULL;
    Node<T>* tmp = src->head;
    while( tmp ) {
        push( tmp->data );
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}

template <typename T> 
stack<T>& stack<T>::operator=( stack<T> src ) // copy the argument is OK here!
{
    stack old;
    old->head = head;
    head = src->head;
    src->head = NULL;
}
```

Since you are learning, this above is a good starting point. You now have to

- Implement the copy-constructor in a way that it does *not* reverse the order of elements
- Understand how exactly the assignment operator works. I used an unusual implementation, but once you understand it, you learned a lot about object lifetime :)

Comment: It didn't solve the problem Daniel. myStack3 still shows irrelevant data. It seems it points to somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You declared something else in class declaration, you wrote `+=` instead of `+` in the definition:

```
stack <T> operator+ (stack <T>);
                  ^

stack <T> stack<T>::operator+= (stack <T> stack1){
                            ^^
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it. I meant +.

Comment: So, the operator works now. How ever you have problems at run-time.